# Global suppression for entire solution (C#)

Tags: c#, code-analysis, suppression

Does any one of you know a way I'd be able to suppress e.g. CA2000 for an entire solution?

I'm thinking of something like a `GlobalSuppressions` class with the following line of code:

```
[assembly: SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Reliability", "CA2000:DisposeObjectsBeforeLosingScope")]
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suppress warning on solution level. Treat warning as error on solution level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18546635/suppress-warning-on-solution-level-treat-warning-as-error-on-solution-level)

Comment: Important to note, that you can edit the file that handles those.  You can extend outward, ReSharper and other platforms already do this, but I believe the answer already exists here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if in a month you are asking why you get a memory leak

Comment: There is a really good reason why you don't want to do this on a global level.

Comment: why do you want to suppress this?

Comment: Because it is my task to do so. Some of our head devs gave me the tasks.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It is done now

Answer (score 9):

Global Suppressions can be configured in [.editorconfig file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options).

1. Create a file called .editorconfig in the root folder of your solution
2. Open in a text editor
3. Add `root = true` in first line
4. Below that line add the rules to disable

   ```
   [*.{cs,vb}]
   dotnet_diagnostic.<Rule_Code>.severity=silent
   ```

Here is an example .editorconfig file

```
root = true

[*.{cs,vb}]
dotnet_diagnostic.CA2000.severity=silent

[*.{cs,vb}]
dotnet_diagnostic.MA0004.severity=silent    # Even works with 3rd part rules/analyser
```

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone stumbles on this, it is possible to create a global suppressions file (Eg: `GlobalSuppressions.cs`), add it "as link" to each project you need to. It should contains lines like:

```cs
[assembly: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Reliability", "CA2007:Consider calling ConfigureAwait on the awaited task", Justification = "ASP.NET Core doesn't use thread context to store request context.", Scope = "module")]
```

For more details see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/in-source-suppression-overview?view=vs-2022#suppress-violations-using-a-global-suppression-file

Answer (score 2):

The best way of doing this is by creating a `Directory.Build.props` file which will be automatically included in all projects in sub-folders to where it is located. Then add the following to the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project>
  <!-- This file will be automatically included in all projects because of its name -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <NoWarn>CA2000</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```